# Bison unexpected indentifier error

Tags: c, bison

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void yyerror(const char *str)
{
        fprintf(stderr,"error: %s\n",str);
}

int yywrap()
{
        return 1;
}

int main()
{
        yyparse();
}
%}

%token TOKMACHINE TOKLOGIN TOKPASSWORD VALUE SPACE NEWLINE
input: auth input | input;
delim: SPACE | NEWLINE;
auth: TOKMACHINE delim VALUE delim TOKLOGIN delim  VALUE delim  TOKPASSWORD delim VALUE delim
{
    printf("Found auth {%s,%s,%s}", $1,$3,$5);
};
```

Here is simple bison grammar, with which I want to parse `.netrc` file.
But I get error on `input` line:

```
netrc.y:23.1-5: syntax error, unexpected identifier:
```

I am new to Flex/Bison, but this example near literal copy from  [here](http://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/lmcdowel/courses/si413/F10/labs/L04/calc1/ex1.html)

Comment: Line 23 is `input: auth input | input;`; columns 1-5 are the identifier `input`, which seems to be what it's complaining about. I don't remember bison well enough to figure out the problem.

Comment: This is **anything but** a near literal copy. Look at the original example exactly and you'll spot a handful of differences, all resulting in various errors. Yacc is unforgiving.

Comment: @Jens Of course, this question is about Bison, not Yacc, but they are part of the same bestiary... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the `%%` delimiter. Make that

```
%}
%token ...

%%
input : ...
```

Comment: I tried that myself on the OP's code. It gets rid of the error message but introduces several more, including `fatal error: start symbol input does not derive any sentence`.

Comment: That would spark another few questions, I guess :-) Contrary to the poster's claim, the referenced copy is vastly different.

Comment: Well, probably I was't right with `literally` word. It is close in sence that uses nothing more complicated.
@Keith Thompson Thank. I got exactly that error. Have you suggestions for them?

Comment: For starters, understand what a grammar rule is. E.g. you should not reference a nonterminal with just itself, as in `input: ... | input`. To express that a nonterminal is a list of one or more of something is done in another way. Any introduction to yacc should explain these things.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `%%` line after your `%token` line to separate the definitions section from the grammar section.